# Moving large files between Windows machines

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet

I need to move a large file from one laptop to another. Can I just join the two machines with an ethernet cable and create a shared folder on my desktop or is it more complicated than that?

**Update**

Windows versions - one laptop has XP the other is Vista
File Size - approx 10G

Comment: How large of a file?

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/6557/whats-the-fastest-way-to-transfer-files-between-2-computers

Comment: @Josh K, larger than any pen drive I have on hand. I think it's about 10 gigs.

Comment: What version of windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can join both PCs with a network cable and copy the file.

To do this you must set up the network, and your file shares.

- Plug each end of the crossover cable into a network port on the back of each computer.
- Open Network and Sharing Center (Start, Control Panel, clicking Network and Internet, Network and Sharing Center)

In the network map at the top of Network and Sharing Center, double-click the Unidentified network‍ icon.

- In Network, click the Information bar containing the following message:

> Network discovery and file sharing are turned off. 
>      Network computers and devices are not visible. Click to change...

and then click Turn on network discovery and file sharing.

Do this on both computers. With any luck, this is all the network set up you will need to do.

---

On the PC with the file, do Properties/Sharing/Share as you mentioned in a comment.

As [r0ca](https://superuser.com/questions/104825/moving-large-files-between-windows-machines/104830#104830) says, the PC that wants the file can then connect with

```
\\name-of-pc-with-the-file\name-of-network-share
```

Comment: (Specifics of the instructions apply to Windows Vista. I will change it if you need instructions on a different version of windows)

Answer (score 5):

Modern ethernet cards will do the crossover for you, so there's no need for a "special cable". Just connect to the two machines, set an IP for them and transfer files.

Comment: How do you set an IP?

Comment: The easiest way is to set it from TCP/IP properties.

For example, on machine #1 - Set the IP as 192.168.1.1, Netmask 255.255.255.0
You can leave the gateway blank, it doesn't matter.

Machine #2, set the IP as 192.168.1.2, Netmask 255.255.255.0

Then go to Start > Run, //192.168.1.1 and you should be able to see the shared folders on Machine #2 and similarly from Machine #1, Try //192.168.1.2

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use a portable media device like a USB HDD or USB key. You can also create a network share and then, transfer your files. It's quite easy.

Start - run: \\IP-or-computername\"Shared"

And then, paste your files.

Comment: What's the difference between that command line and doing Properties/Sharing/Share this folder?

Comment: That command connects to an existing share. It does not actually create one, as your GUI approach does.

Answer (score 1):

When copying large files do NOT use windows explorer.  Start a command prompt and use the copy/xcopy command.

Comment: Why? Is it faster that way? More reliable?

Comment: Yes to both. That stupid little flying document causes all kinds of trouble.

Comment: I do weekly backups of 60Gb+ using copy and paste in Windows Explorer. This is from a remote system, over network, to a USB 2.0 external HD. Never had a problem yet.

Comment: Some people are still nervous about using the Windows Explorer to copy files, because we've been burned in the past with old versions of Windows and with unreliable networks.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a special kind of ethernet cable called a "crossover" cable. Far easier to borrow a hub, or use a USB stick to transfer :)

Comment: You don't necessarily need a crossover cable; many Ethernet cards and switches will auto-crossover, so either type of cable should work.

Comment: @sblair - while it is true that some ethernet adapters and switches do support 'auto-crossover', a downvote based on the purely speculative assumption that the OP's network controllers do belong indeed into this category is ridiculous! remember: assumption is the mother of all Eff Ups.

Comment: @Molly I didn't down-vote this answer - why do you assume I did...? And my comment states that many devices support this, implying of course that some do not.

Comment: @sblair - my apologies ... had to be just another drive-by downvote. :)